# Создание библиотеки в QtCreator

Tags: c++, linux, windows

Всем привет, хочу научиться писать свои библиотеки, поставил задачу написать библиотеку под две системы Windows и Linux. Может кто знает где посмотреть настройку pro файла или может чего другого. Ситуация такая, необходимо написать 1 .h файл и 2 .cpp файла. В .h файле обьявление функций, а в каждом из .cpp файле реализация под каждую систему. Условно есть функция она работает с файловой системой. В linux и windows они разные, и я хочу что бы реализации были в 2 разных .cpp файлах и либа в зависимости от системы собиралась с нужным .cpp файлом. КАК ТАКОЕ СДЕЛАТЬ ?

Comment: вам обязательно нужно использовать qmake как систему сборки?

Answer (score 0):

Делаешь общий класс, cpp/h, в нем импортируешь оба класса, в которых закрываешь код через ifdef

Comment: абсолютно согласен, но автор хочет два разных файла, так что это не совсем то о чем спрашивал ТС. Сдесь вопрос скорее про систему сборки

Comment: Так будет два разных файла, третий чтоб их совместить. Можно конечно  совместить в одном из двух, все тоже самое, но не красиво

Comment: так в том то и дело, что через систему сборки это можно сделать через 2 файла и даже без `ifdef` (тобишь все будет "красиво")

Comment: по мне это задачка препроцессора, да и в взрослых либах делают через препроцессор.

Comment: в случае, если имеются разные файлы для разных опрерационок - это уже плохая задачка для препроцессора. Вы ведь ради этого предлагаете ввести еще один файл, хотя в системе сборки достаточно указать один из имеющихся файлов. ИМХО, лучший вариант при котором меньше телодвижений

Comment: хотя я никогда и не создавал отдельных файлов под разные варианты - привык решать все локально в файле (да и это редко приходится делать)